# Remove appended # from url in ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my rails application(rails 2.3.4 and ruby 1.8.7) When i click on News , an ajax call is made and data is loaded.

```
 <a href="News" onclick="load_feed();"><u>Show More...</u></a>

 <script>
  function load_feed()
 {
 $.ajax({
   url: this.url,
 dataType: 'script'
 })
$('div .rss_feed_1').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "news_feed_data")   %>");
 }
</script>
```

When i click an ajax call is made and data is loaded. but the url changes to

http://localhost:3000/us/dropbox#News from http://localhost:3000/us/dropbox , Is there any way out that i can get this url  http://localhost:3000/us/dropbox/News by removing the #.

Comment: I'm not sure but try to add `return false` in the end of `load_feed()`

Comment: to be honest, I never really thought of a `#` as being any more ugly to look at than a `/`.

Comment: It's never about # being ugly, i want it to be removed as my req.

Answer (score 3):

Using the new Javascript [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) you can create pretty looking URL:s while staying on the same page and only using AJAX for data fetching.

Here is [an example](http://html5.gingerhost.com) of it. This is also the method Facebook uses.

Comment: Upvoted for awesome link. Github also makes use of this when exploring file structures etc.

Comment: +1 for the only correct answer. However, be aware that is not supported in any current version of IE, and may have issues in some other browsers - see caniuse.com/#search=pushstate for browser support table.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put 'return false;' at the end of your function or write 'onclick="load_feed(); return false;"'. So you prevent that the default action (following the link) will be triggered.

Comment: This is not what he is asking for. The problem isn't that he is directed to /news.
The problem is that he thinks that the hashtag url #news looks ugly and would like to have a proper url like /news

Comment: @GhostRider styrr is trying to prevent '#' from being appended in the first place, which is actually the problem you describe in the title.  The actual question doesn't exactly match the title, so you might want to fix that.  That said, Zeta Two has your answer